# Yii module efficient asset dependency management

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

I have used Yii modules heavily. Inside module's init method ,I am registering javascripts. All modules have their own set of assets ( js ) and there are also dependencies between modules. So a module A sometimes renders views from module B, where Module B can be for notitfication.

So having only 1 CDN and lot of JS being downloaded, 1 per module and about 10 modules ,it is also slowing down the page load. Each modules JS is a Self invoking anonymous function with following structure with average 1k lines of code - all jquery dom manipulations , click, infinte scroll etc ..

STRUCTURE:

```
var moduleA = (function($){

    //Private:
    $(document).ready(){
        myHandler.method1();
        myHandler.method2();
    }


    var myHandler = {

        method1 : function() {... }
        method2 : function() {... }

    };

    //Public :
    return {
        m1 : method1;
    };


})($);
```

As I have already added Module pattern to JS, should I rely on Yii base CModule init() for managing inter-module JS dependencies or use AMD patterns like Require JS. Any further suggestion would be welcome because I am facing real slowness in first load though it is running on 1 Amazon EC2 small instance and there are not much users at present and database is fairly normalized.

I have returned result of renderPartial from controller to JS and from JS inserting to specific div id in case of all AJAX requests by doing `$("#div").update(renderPartHtml)` after each Ajax call, as i needed some pre-Ajax checks.

THanks

Comment: Include your module's JS via a custom clientScript that will combine them in one file, like CSS/Js compressors are used to it.

Comment: @Pentium10, do you mean using custom clientScript like NLSClientScript - http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nlsclientscript/